# Simplifying an inner join query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL inner join query that I'm trying to simplify using the `as` keyword.

Original query:

```
SELECT u.user
     , g.group
     , b.type
     , b.name
     , b.count
     , b.date
  FROM profile.user u
  JOIN profile.group g 
    ON g.GroupID = u.GroupID
  JOIN main.set b
    ON b.ID = u.GroupID
 GROUP 
    BY u.username
     , u.GroupID
```

Simplified query:

```
# Returns user and ID
select  profile.user as user,
        profile.group as group,
        main.set as b
  from user,
    inner join group on group.ID = user.ID
    inner join b on b.ID = user.ID
  group by user.name
```

Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax.

Comment: The first query doesn't really make sense; you have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions.

Comment: If MySQL tells you "You have an error ... at line 6" - look at line 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Table aliases occur in the FROM portion.
2. Column/Field  Aliases occur in the SELECT portion.
3. the schema.TableName is what's in the FROM you originally had which can be aliased as tables...

.

```
SELECT UM.username
     , GM.GroupID
     , B.Type
     , B.BatchName
     , B.Count
     , B.Date
FROM inno_Profiles.pUserMatch UM
INNER JOIN inno_Profiles.pGroupMatch GM 
   on GM.GroupID = UM.GroupID
INNER JOIN inno_donorsearch.batches  B
   on B.ID = UM.GroupID
GROUP BY UM.username, UM.GroupID
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the group by is getting you though since you have no aggregations as strawberry points out in comments.